# If a family of functions has an unbounded derivative, is it necessarily not uniformly equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity, equicontinuity

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around uniform equicontinuity for a family of functions. I can often spot if a family is uniformly equicontinuous, but have trouble telling when they're not, and I was wondering if there are any signs which would allow me to spot the non-uniformly equicontinuous families. Intuitively, it seems to me that if the derivative of a family of functions is unbounded then it can't be uniformly equicontinuous.

For example, if the family is given by $F=\{f_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb N$,  $|f_n'(x)|=|e^{n}|$, then it seems to me that the family cannot be uniformly equicontinuous.

Since this isn't a common theorem, I'm guessing my intuitiong is wrong, but a proof or a counter example would be very helpful, thanks!

Note: my definition of uniform equicontinuity is the following:

A family of functions, $F$, consisting of functions $f:(X,d)\to (Y,\rho)$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $X$ if for every $\epsilon >0 $ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $$d(x,y)<\delta \implies \rho(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$$
for all $x\in X$ and $f \in F$. The key here is that $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$, but not on $x$ or $f$.

Comment: do you mean like $\sup|f'_n(x)|$ is increasing and going to infinity?

Comment: @clark, yes that's what I mean

Comment: $F$ could have just one member $f.$ There exists a uniformly continuous,  differentiable $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with an unbounded derivative,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for instance $ f_n (x) = \dfrac{\sin n^2x}{n}$ then $f_n$ is an equicontinuous family. For a proof see at the end.

However, $\sup|f'_n(x)| = n $.

So, the point is imagine a family where the values increasingly oscillate faster and faster (making the sup of the derivative increase)  however the values are staying close to each other.

I think the moral of the story is, when $\sup|f'_n(x)| \leq M,~\forall n$ then the values of the family of functions can be simultaneously controlled, however even when the derivatives behave radically differently the values can still be not very different.

**Proof for equicontinuity:**

Observe $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y) | \leq \frac{1}{n}|\sin(n^2x) -\sin (n^2y)     | \leq \frac{2}{n}.  $$

Now, let $\epsilon >0$ and find $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have $\dfrac{2}{n}<\epsilon$.

Also, for $1\leq i\leq N-1$ we can find $ \delta _i  $ such that $|f_i(x) -f_i(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta _i$.

From here we choose $\delta = \min_{1\leq i\leq N-1} \delta _i  $, and we obtain
$|f_m(x) -f_m(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta $ for all $m$.

Comment: Thanks very much, I can see what you mean by plotting this function for a few different n. Would you mind giving a proof that this family is equicontinuous though?

Comment: @user428487 I have included a proof for the equicontinuity, please tell me if you need any further details

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the family of functions consisting of just one function, namely $f(x)$ on $[0,1],$ where $f(x)=x^2\sin (1/x^2),x\in (0,1],$  $f(0)=0.$

Comment: If we want an infinite family of functions, I guess we can take $f$ as in your answer, and  $\mathcal{F} = \{f+n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: @Ovi Yes, but it seemed to me a stronger result to show boundedness of $f'$ need not hold even for just one function.

Comment: Ah I see ${}{}{}$